# Why do shows say "Netflix Original" when they are reruns from other channels?

Tags: terminology, netflix

Why do shows say "Netflix Original" when they are reruns from other channels?

It almost seems childish that a company like Netflix would put something like that before a show they didn't produce or create themselves but maybe I don't understand the industry lingo.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @Yasskier - The Great British Baking Show which was created and produced by Channel 4 in UK.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_British_Bake_Off: "In 2018, the Channel 4 Series 8 was made available in the United States on Netflix as "Collection 5" and a "Netflix original production" alongside the four series previously broadcast on PBS. In addition, Netflix added The Great British Baking Show: The Beginnings which features the British series 3."". I guess Netflix bought rights to it? Netflix wouldn't call it it's own if it didn't have legal rights.

Comment: @blankip Please edit your question to include examples. Comments are ephemeral.

Comment: GBBO was not "created by Channel 4". GBBO is produced by Love Productions and was initially broadcast on the BBC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Netflix_original_programming):

> Netflix's original productions also include continuations of cancelled series from other networks, as well as **licensing or co-producing content from international broadcasters for exclusive broadcast in other territories**, which is also branded in those regions as Netflix original content.

From [another Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Netflix_exclusive_international_distribution_programming):

> These products, even though Netflix lists them as Netflix Originals, are programs that have been aired in different countries, and **Netflix has bought exclusive distribution rights to stream them in other various countries**. They may be available on Netflix in their home territory and other markets where Netflix does not have the first run license, without the Netflix Original label, some time after their first-run airing on their original broadcaster.

[***Quartz*** explains](https://qz.com/1545594/netflix-doesnt-make-most-of-its-originals-now-thats-changing/):

> **Netflix uses the term “original” to delineate between movies and series that are exclusive to its platform**, and those that are aggregated from other studios after first being made available elsewhere. Original can refer to a few things: content such as *Stranger Things* that are self produced, programming like *Narcos* that are licensed exclusively from other studios and branded as Netflix originals, or licensed content such as *You* and *Riverdale* that may air on TV in some markets but stream first on Netflix in other parts of the world.

Comment: This is obviously the correct answer but obviously Netflix does not understand the meaning of the word "original" or is playing on the word to extremes.